# How to migrate spring-boot-actuator from version 1.5.17 to 2.7.3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

How can I migrate spring-boot-actuator from version 1.5.17 to 2.7.3 ?

Seems like in version 2.7.3 the following classes no longer exists:

- `EndpointAutoConfiguration`
- `EndpointHandlerMapping`
- `MvcEndpoint`
- `HealthMvcEndpoint`
- `HealthEndpoint`

Any suggestion?

This is my code:

**pom xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

**SpringConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@Import(EndpointAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("com.bael.package.food")
public class SpringConfig {

@Bean
@Autowired
public EndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping(Collection<? extends MvcEndpoint> urls){
  return new EndpointHandlerMapping(urls);
}


@Bean
@Autowired
public HealthMvcEndpoint healthMvcEndpoint(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
  return new HealthMvcEndpoint(healthEndpoint, urls);
 } 
}
```

Comment: Some of those classes still exist, e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/EndpointAutoConfiguration.html, but it looks like they have been moved to another class and/or renamed.

Comment: In any case, read this section of the Spring 2.0 Migration Guide (and the linked documentation): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#spring-boot-actuator (use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html instead of the broken link)